# How to use array.find comparing it with another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have two javascript array objects **designs** and **articles**.

```
var designs = [
    {
        design_id:"bwbmbqlujurv", article_id:14782, name:"adidas demogorgon black"

    }, 
    {
        design_id:"lg9yba2gkcwr", article_id:14782, name:"harry potter wand"

    }, 
    {
        design_id:"ztvx3yikkkyx", article_id:5570, name:"hogwarts map"
    }, 
    {
        design_id:"hlzd4afi9en5", article_id:5570, name:"lannister lion"
    }, 
    {
        design_id:"sdwererefwff", article_id:14782, name:"pokemon bulbasaur"
    },
];

var articles = [
    {
        article_id:6508, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"tee man two sides"
    },
    {
        article_id:13510, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"tee woman two sides"
    },
    {
        article_id:5570, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"necktie"
    },
    {
        article_id:14782, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"sweetwear with hood"
    },
]
```

I want get the value of the first element in the array **articles** that meets these conditions:

```
article => article.article_id == design.article_id || article.dsn_shared_art_id == design.article_id
```

I tried with .find, but it doesn't work:

```
this.designs.forEach(function(design) {
    var $artdata = this.articles.find(article => article.article_id == design.article_id || article.dsn_shared_art_id == design.article_id);
    console.log($artdata);//undefined
}.bind(this));
```

How can I make this right?

Comment: `.bind(this)` <-- any relevant reason for such binding? there is no need to bind anything here. Your current code, with the given example, by targeting `designs` and `articles` instead of `this.designs` and `this.articles` works just as intended. It would be helpful to have to whole vuejs component part.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine for me:

```js
var designs = [
    {
        design_id:"bwbmbqlujurv", article_id:14782, name:"adidas demogorgon black"

    }, 
    {
        design_id:"lg9yba2gkcwr", article_id:14782, name:"harry potter wand"

    }, 
    {
        design_id:"ztvx3yikkkyx", article_id:5570, name:"hogwarts map"
    }, 
    {
        design_id:"hlzd4afi9en5", article_id:5570, name:"lannister lion"
    }, 
    {
        design_id:"sdwererefwff", article_id:14782, name:"pokemon bulbasaur"
    },
];

var articles = [
    {
        article_id:6508, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"tee man two sides"
    },
    {
        article_id:13510, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"tee woman two sides"
    },
    {
        article_id:5570, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"necktie"
    },
    {
        article_id:14782, dsn_shared_art_id:null, name:"sweetwear with hood"
    },
]


designs.forEach(function(design) {
var $artdata = articles.find(article => article.article_id == design.article_id || article.dsn_shared_art_id == design.article_id);
console.log($artdata);//undefined
}.bind(this));
```

I suspect your problem might have something to do with `this` context. Try an arrow function instead, `designs.forEach(design => ... )`

Comment: what is the need of `.bind(this)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `this` from `this.designs` and `this.articles`. Then remove `.bind(this)` as you dont need to bind them with `this`.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4qfnou8L/) is a working jsfiddle.
But if you are doing it in vuejs then just change your `forEach` method like this:

```
this.designs.forEach((design) => {
  var $artdata = this.articles.find(article => article.article_id == design.article_id || article.dsn_shared_art_id == design.article_id);
  console.log($artdata);//undefined
})
```

As scope of `this` is the inner `function` in you code. Just replaced that will arrow function. Or you can try with setting value of `this` outside like `let self = this` as said in other answers

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like below

```
var self = this;
self.designs.forEach(function(design) {
    var artdata = self.articles.find(article => article.article_id == design.article_id || article.dsn_shared_art_id == design.article_id);
    console.log(artdata);
});
```

The issue is with the scope of `this`. Inside your `forEach` `this.articles` does not exists. Hence the undefined error.